# How to parse date with "mmmm d, YYYY h:M a" format in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have this date,

- April 22nd 2020 12:34 am
- April 21st 2020 3:14 am
- April 22nd 2020 10:13 pm
- April 23rd 2020 8:46 pm
- April 21st 2020 2:32 am
- April 21st 2020 2:22 am

I am replacing

"nd 2020" with ", 2020" and so on and bringing a date to this format using this formula,

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Last Action At,'st 2020', ', 2020'),'th 2020', ', 2020'), 'nd 2020', ', 2020')
```

And storing it in "Date STR" field

- April 22, 2020 12:34 am
- April 21, 2020 3:14 am
- April 22, 2020 10:13 pm
- April 23, 2020 8:46 pm
- April 21, 2020 2:32 am
- April 21, 2020 2:22 am

But, further, this date is not accepted when I used the formula:

```
todate(Date STR,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

I even tried

```
todate(Date STR,'%m%m%m%m, %d, %Y%Y%Y%Y %h:%m %a'.'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 0) Summary

Use either (#1 **OR** #2) of the below suggestions:

1. The updated answer makes use of the new [`PARSE_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739558) function released in the [17 Sep 2020 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467#sep-17-2020) to Google Data Studio;
2. The original post uses the **Compatibility Mode** Date and Time function, [`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300).

### 1) Update ([`PARSE_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739558))

Create the following [`PARSE_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739558) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%B %d %Y %I:%M %p", REGEXP_REPLACE(Last Action At, "(.*\\d+)[a-z]+(.*)", "\\1 \\2"))
```

Added a [New Page to the Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ee13d017-b1c1-4fe8-a0bc-7a470eebe462/page/TAdiB) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

### 2) Original Post ([`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300))

It can be achieved using the below combination of [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) and [`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) functions:

```
TODATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Last Action At, "([A-Za-z]+ \\d+)[A-Za-z]+(.*)", "\\1 \\2"), "%B %d %Y %I:%M %p", "%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Set the Date Type as required (for example):

- Date YYYYMMDD
- Date Hour YYYYMMDDhhmm
- Date Hour Minute YYYYMMDDhhmm

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ee13d017-b1c1-4fe8-a0bc-7a470eebe462) to elaborate:

[image]